# intellij still comitting files in .ignore

Tags: intellij-idea, gitignore

I have this directory in my .gitignore file which is located in the root direcotry.

```
/node_modules/
```

But when I commit the project in intellij, the ignored directory is still showing in the commit. What am I doing wrong? (see screenshot below)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwD7d.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created and added it into git this directory before you created/filled gitignore file, then you must remove this directory with his files from git. Use git rm --cached -r on this directory. This command remove from git tracked files.

Btw, it is not problem of intellij, but problem in git.

Comment: I haven't comitted that directory before, I checked the git repo and it's not in there. I ran your command and got this error "fatal: /node_modules: '/node_modules' is outside repository"

Comment: And if you run git status, is it directory in list? Git rm --cached  Will remove tracked files from git, which Will not commit them.

Comment: When I ran git status I got a bunch of these:


            new file:   node_modules/rxjs/operator/switchMap.d.ts
        new file:   node_modules/rxjs/operator/switchMap.js
        new file:   node_modules/rxjs/operator/switchMap.js.map
        new file:   node_modules/rxjs/operator/switchMapTo.d.ts
        new file:   node_modules/rxjs/operator/switchMapTo.js
        new file:   node_modules/rxjs/operator/switchMapTo.js.map

etc...
etc..

Comment: Thanks I ran Git rm --cached again and it solved it. I had to use -r.